# Flutter get Data Value from GetStorage List

Tags: android, list, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

i wanna get a Data from GetStorage(),

i got a Shop List and i can use it as Static for only page, that way im saving my List in GetStorage,if i go to another Page that will showed also. Like a SharedPreferences. How can i show a data from GetStorage List Value , like

Text(basket[name]), that will show only the Names,
Text(basket[price]), that will show only Prices,

```
var basketsd = GetStorage("totalList");
```

My ProductModel for Shop,

```
class PriceModel2 {
  final String name;
  final double price;
  PriceModel2({
    this.name,
    this.price,
  });
}
```

its also not worked.

```
Text(controller.basketsd.read(["name"])

 Container(
            height: Get.size.height * 0.3,
            child: Obx(() => ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.basket.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: Get.size.width,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              controller.basket
                                  .remove(controller.basket[index]);
                            },
                            child: (Text(controller.basketsd.read(["name"]) +
                                " " +
                                controller.basket[index].price.toString() +
                                " €"))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                })),
          ),
```

Codes show like this ,
(https://prnt.sc/1fs6mbf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple issues here. At least from what you're sharing, you're never really storing your `PriceModel2` object properly. If you try and store a random custom object, `GetStorage` will not know what to do with it. (Neither would `SharedPreferences` in the same scenario).

So for starters, you can implement a `toMap` function that converts it to a map that `GetStorage` can read.

Add this to your `PriceModel2` class.

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'price': price,
    };
  }
```

Then you add a named constructor in the same class so you can create your object from the `Map` that you stored.

```
 PriceModel2.fromMap(Map map)
      : name = map['name'],
        price = map['price'];
```

I also suggest, regardless of whichever storage library you're using, keeping all storage related functionality, including `boxes` in this case, in its own class, that stores and returns whatever data you need. This way if you ever need to upgrade to `Hive`, `ObjectBox` etc... you do it in one class and not all over your app.

An example would look like this.

```
class Database extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage();

  Future<void> initStorage() async {
    await GetStorage.init();
  }

  void storePriceModel(PriceModel2 model) {
    box.write('model', model.toMap());
  }

  PriceModel2 restoreModel() {
    final map = box.read('model') ?? {};
    return PriceModel2.fromMap(map);
  }
}
```

Then you would initialize your controller and storage in main.

```
void main() async {
  await Get.put(Database()).initStorage();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

An example of storing a model would look like this.

```
     ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final model = PriceModel2(name: 'test name', price: 23.0);
                Get.find<Database>().storePriceModel(model);
              },
              child: Text('Store Model'),
            ),
```

And displaying the storage data in the UI could be done like so.

```
Text(Get.find<Database>().restoreModel().name)
```

You don't need an `Obx` just to display the stored data because its not an observable stream based variable.

As for displaying a list of products you do the same thing but store a list of maps instead of a single map.

If you need help with that then share how you're trying to add and store to the `PriceModel2` list.